# Save only a single element into a ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have an app which has a Meet and this meet could have only one guest or more than one guest. I defined Meet model with a ManyToManyField relationship with User and a field to choice if the meet is going to be with single guest or it'll be in a team (with many guests) as follow:

```
class Meet(IndexedTimeStampedModel):
    kind_meet = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                    choices=MEET_CHOICES)
    guests = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='guests')
```

I did a form with Meet Model, so first the user select the kind of meet that he would like to do and on the next page he will select the guest or guests of the meeting.

My fight is, if the user choose a single meet how can I force him to select just one guest on a select box in a template?

On my ModelForm, I try to restrict this defining the widget of guests field as Select but ManyToManyField just accept a list of values and Select return the value as string not a list. This cause an error

> "Enter a list of values"

when I submit the form. My second try was change the widget to SelectMultiple but this allow the user to select more than guest.

```
class Meta:
    model = Meet
    widgets = {
        'guests': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    }
```

Does anyone has an idea how can I force a user to select just one guest (value) in a m2m relation?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep using the Select widget and in your view after the form submission and convert the submission to a list with something like:

```py
# copy from immutable QueryDict
data = {**request.POST}
# change your data from the guest input to be a list
data["guests"] = [data.pop("guests", [])]
form = MeetForm(data=data)
if form.is_valid():
 . . .
```